# how to manage webtab movements without page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, infragistics

I have an infragistics web tab (`Ultrawebtab`) and i have a panel which i set visible false in designer.I want to display panel content only in one of the tab and clear in rest of the tab.I can do it by enabling `autopostback` true and managing in `tabclick` event .But i dont iwant it since it will refresh the page everytime when i click the tabs.How to do it in different way like `mouse over` event or any other events in asp.net

```
<igtab UltraWebTab id="ulTab"><Tabs/><igtab>
```

Comment: I fixed this issue by moving ultratab to the required <td>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by moving ultratab to the required